# how to temporarily pass form validation for a form field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following model:

```
class Regulatory(models.Model):  
    field1 = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES, default=None, )
    field2 = models.IntegerField(choices=THREE_CHOICES, default=None,)
```

I have the following form:

```
class RegulatoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    field1 = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    field2 = forms.IntegerField(required=False)


    class Meta:
        model = Regulatory
        widgets = {
                   'field1': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={"required": "required"}), 
                   'field2': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={"required": "required"}), 
       }

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.site_id = kwargs.pop('site_id', None)
        super(RegulatoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

     def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        if self.site_id == 2:
            data['field1'] = 0
            data['field2'] = 0
        else:
            return data
```

When I submit the form, I still get the validation error:

> field error: This field cannot be null.

How can I allow the required fields to temporarily pass through to my view so I can set them before saving?

Comment: If you are always going to use both fields, add `blank=True` to your fields in the model. This lets them be blank when submitting through a form. If you want to be able to use `None` as a value, also set `null=True`. `default=None` isn't the right syntax for what you want.

Comment: @user2896976 If I don't use default=None then it checks one of my radio buttons automatically.

Comment: How about if you add `initial=None` to your form field definitions?

Answer (score 0):

I added blank=True and I was off to the races.